# SDN4 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long when using AttributeConverter

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Firstly I may doing something unnecessary here but I believe the issue is nothing to do with that. I am trying to store `ZonedDateTime` values in neo4j with this converter class:

```
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long toGraphProperty(ZonedDateTime value) {
        return value != null ? value.toEpochSecond() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime toEntityAttribute(Long value) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        Instant i = Instant.ofEpochSecond(value);
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, zoneId);
    }
}
```

Saving values seems to work fine but when retrieving (with findOne for example) I get the following:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of co.sens.data.models.Transaction
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.loadById(SessionResponseHandler.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:36)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findOne(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.findOne(Unknown Source)
    at co.sens.data.AccountRepositoryTest.testTransactionsForAccount(AccountRepositoryTest.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at co.sens.data.ZonedDateTimeConverter.toEntityAttribute(ZonedDateTimeConverter.java:13)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.FieldWriter.write(FieldWriter.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:94)
    ... 62 more
```

Is this a bug or have I made a mistake in how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the query results are returned over the wire, JSON loses the type information; in this case, the numeric value is interpreted to be an integer.

Changing your converter to handle `Number` should take care of this. Here's an example: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/typeconversion/DateLongConverter.java

Comment: This appears to work but I can't see where these dates are stored in the graph.

Comment: It'll be stored as a property value on the node where you defined this converter

Comment: For the annotated property postDate if I use ```MATCH (t:Transaction) RETURN t``` then every result has no postDate field. Using a Spring repository to return the results I can see the date field is populated. Where is this value stored?

Comment: Actually the date field seems to be cached from a previous insert. If I restart the web server and try to retrieve the results there is no postDate. My entity property is ```@Convert(ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
    public ZonedDateTime postDate;```

Comment: In fact the cypher being by SDN4 when updating the postDate field on the entity is: ```{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ($44) WHERE id($44)={$44} MATCH ($43) WHERE id($43)={$43} MERGE ($44)-[_0:`CATEGORY`]->($43) WITH $43,$44,_0 MATCH ($50) WHERE id($50)={$50} MERGE ($44)-[_1:`INSTITUTION`]->($50) RETURN id(_0) AS _0, id(_1) AS _1","parameters":{"$43":43,"$44":44,"$50":50},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}```

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at this and get back to you

Comment: Which version of SDN are you using? Just tried your converter and it works fine when I save an entity

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. The converter works fine if saving a new entity but doesn't seem to save if adding to an already existing record. You can see the cypher above was from an update where I updated the CATEGORY and INSTITUTION relationships but I also set the postDate property. The record did not have this property originally so I think this is could be a bug where newly-added properties are ignored when updating.

Comment: Ah okay, did not realize that. Will give it a go again

Comment: Is this property on the relationship entity? Or on an entity which does not seem to get updated when you save it (and change relationships)?

Comment: This is a property on an entity so the second case. Pattern is: get entity with findOne(), set new property value and update old properties including relationship properties, call entity repository save()

Comment: Tried this- get entity with findOne, update the ZonedDateTime value,change a relationship, save. The property as well as relationship are updated. Same with a collection of relationship entities. Could you either mail me some code (luanne at graphaware dot com) or log an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm with more details/a test?

Comment: Thanks, Luanne. I'll try to get some code together to recreate this. Going back over my steps I think the issue is this: Create entity, save, add ZonedDateTime property to entity, retrieve entity set new property, save, new property is not saved.